# Using named functions or putting them inside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big code base of an Angular directive and I have been declaring functions like this:

```
$scope.doFoo = function() { ... };
```

because I thought Angular could manage/release the functions when required (not very sure where I read that).

Anyways, a contributor to my project told me he thinks this is not true. Is there any difference between declaring functions as scope variable or just declaring them as plain functions like this:

```
function doFoo() { ... };
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: If you don't need that function in other parts of your project except for logic in your directive than use named function, like private method in OOP.

Answer (score 3):

With the former method, it's easy to clutter the scope with functions that may not be needed by the view (such as utility/helper functions inside the controller). I think it's logical to have a list of functions/variables used by the view at the top, assigned to the scope. Ie:

`$scope.doFoo = doFoo;`

Then, towards the bottom of the file, you can organize your functions. Ie:

`function doFoo() { ... ]`

Without doing `$scope.doFoo`, you will not be able to use doFoo in your template (such as `<div ng-click="doFoo()">`).

In this way, if `doFoo()` needed to use some helper function, you could have that declared somewhere in the controller and not clutter the scope by adding it.

I prefer using the controllerAs syntax, and binding `vm` to `this`, but that's a different story all together. (Can read about that style preference [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers).)

Comment: Are there any performance gains when using named functions instead of scoped functions?

Comment: Performance in terms of load? No, but you will reduce scope clutter, which can help make your code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Zack Tanner's answer is correct (and succinct!), but here's some supplementary information that may also help you out.

First, here are some terms we can agree on:

---

**function Declaration**

```
function doFoo() {
  //...
}
```

This declares a function inside of the current function scope (closure)

**function Expression**

```
$scope.doFoo = function() {
  //...
}
```

This declares a function as belonging to an object

---

So what's the difference and why should you care?  Here's Zack Tanner's explanation in action:

```
angular.module("myModule").controller(["$scope", function($scope) {
  var self = this;

  $scope.doFoo = doFoo;
  $scope.doBar = doBar;

  ////Implementation////

  function doFoo() {
    // do foo stuff
  }

  function doBar() {
    // do bar stuff
  }
}]);
```

First of all, this is probably blatantly (and rightfully) stolen from the wisdom that comes of programming in C/C++ or [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).  In either case, the reason this works (and would even work if you put a `return` before the comment in the controller) is because of **Function Hoisting**.  Basically, it comes down to a simple rule: **Function Declarations will always be "hoisted" to the top of the scope they are declared in**.  The same is actually true for `var`iables, too!

To answer your question directly, I don't know about Angular's ability to release or manage functions (I doubt it does?), but it does pay in this case to declare your functions and assign them to your `$scope`.  Also, "controller *as*" syntax is indeed awesome, so consider using that if possible (no `$scope`, plus no weirdness with the prototype chain!).

tl;dr use `function doFoo() { //... }`

Answer (score 1):

Any functions (methods?) bound to `$scope` or a controller (via controllerAs) will be available on the view they are attached to. Functions named in a more traditional way `function doFoo() { ... }` will only be accessible in their respective (**[lexical](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch2.md)**) scopes (be that a controller, service, directive, etc.). Basically, `$scope` allows you to use your functions outside of its lexical scope (to clarify, $scope is an object that is available outside the lexical scope of the controller/directive, just like declaring functions inside a service, you can't use them elsewhere unless you attach them to a returned object).

Each have their place in an application, it's really up to how you want to use the function.

Comment: Are there any performance gains when using named functions instead of scoped functions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a reasonable difference , you only need to bind functions to scope that are used within the views. There is no need to pollute scope with things that are never used in views.

A common style guide best practice is also to declare functions below scope declarations to make it easier to review what is contained within the scope easier

Example:

```
// show all the scope related stuff at top of component
$scope.foo = foo;// reference to function below    

// all the business stuff at bottom of component
function foo(){}//used in view

function bar(){} // only used as utility in controller
```

Good reference:  [John Papa Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: Are there any performance gains when using named functions instead of scoped functions?

Comment: gains will be  not polluting the scope with what isn't needed

Comment: Yeah, if there are any performance gains, it's negligible at best. The primary benefit is keeping your code organized.